# Given $X,Y\sim i.i.U[0,1]$, what is $P(X<Y)$?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Let **a, b** be real numbers randomly selected independently and uniformly from the range of (0,1).

What is **P(a < b)**?

The problem here is that **a** can be equal to **b**, so is 
**P(a < b)  ≈   0.5** or 
**P(a < b)  →   0.5** formally correct? Or anything else?

What I'm looking for here is a correct formal way to write this probability down.

Comment: The probability of having a single value is zero, if the the probability density is $f(x)$ then the probability that the outcome is equal to $a$ is $\int_a^a f(x)dx=0$ because the lower and upper limit are the same.

Comment: "random real numbers between 0 and 1" does not contain enough information to determine $p(a<b)$ (though it can be guessed that  independence and uniform distribution were intended).

Comment: @JuhoKokkala correct

Comment: @fcop  does it mean that in my case, p(a < b) = 0.5 and p(a = b) = 0?

Comment: Would the probability not be: $\int_{0}^{b} f(x) dx$ - $\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx$? This is assuming that $b \geq a$. Now, if $a = b$ then this becomes $\int_{0}^{b} f(x) dx$ - $\int_{0}^{b} f(x) dx = 0$.

Comment: @Riko, it is best to edit these facts into the question rather than leave them in the comments, since not everybody will read the comments and comments may eventually be deleted. I have done this for you in this case.

Comment: thanks @Silverfish I thought that random selection automatically  assumes independent and uniform distribution. Wouldn't it be semi-random otherwise? Sorry, but I still can't find a clear answer to what is p(a<b) eual to in these comments

Comment: The uniform distribution is not the only way to select two numbers between zero and one at random - see e.g. the [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). And just because two numbers are chosen uniformly on (0,1) doesn't mean they are independent: e.g. if $X \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$ then so is $Y=1-X$, but clearly $X$ and $Y$ are dependent.

Comment: All the following material has appeared elsewhere on this site (search if you need details): Making *no* assumptions about the distribution, it is trivial that $\Pr(a\lt b)=\Pr(b\lt a)$. It is axiomatic that $1=\Pr(a\lt b) + \Pr(a=b) + \Pr(a \gt b)$. Algebra implies $\Pr(a\lt b) = (1-\Pr(a=b))/2.$ Any distribution for which $\Pr(a=b)=0$ is *non-discrete.* Such distributions include all continuous distributions, such as the Uniform$(0,1)$ distribution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ are independent and identically distributed as $U[0,1]$, then $P(a \lt b) = 0.5$. It is also true that $P(a \le b) = 0.5$, because $P(a = b) = 0.$

In fact, if $a$ and $b$ are independent and identically distributed from any continuous distribution on the real numbers, then $P(a \lt b) = 0.5$, $P(a \le b) = 0.5$, and $P(a = b) = 0.$

Comment: They dont even need to be independent, exchangeable is enough

Answer (score 4):

For independent continuous $U(0,1)$ random variables we have (taking into account that their density is constant and equal to $1$)
$$P(a<b) =P(a\leq b)= \int_0^1 \int_0^b da\,db = \int_0^1(b-0)\, db $$

$$=\int_0^1b\, db = \frac 12 b^2 \big|^1_0 = \frac 12\cdot1^2 - \frac 12\cdot 0^2 = \frac 12$$

Answer (score -1):

If we start with an infinitely-large ordered set and we pick two elements from the set, we know that one (and only one) of the following situations can be correct:

- a < b
- a = b
- a > b

We can state:

- P( a = b ) = 0 (assuming selection from an infinite set of values)
- P( a < b ) = P ( a > b ) (because a and b are independently selected)

Therefore P( a < b ) = 0.5.

Your example refer to independent selection from the set of all real numbers in the range (0, 1), so this result applies.

Comment: **Your first statement does not follow from the assumptions.**  For instance, let the underlying distribution be [geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with parameter $p$, $0\lt p\lt 1$, where the probability associated with a natural number $n$ is $(1-p)^n p$.  Although the natural numbers are infinite and ordered, $$\Pr(a=b)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty ((1-p)^n p)^2 = \frac{p}{2-p}\ne 0.$$